# Overwrite Instagram Follow button text

Tags: javascript, button, instagram

I am using this tool http://instafollowbutton.com/ in order to create a follow button for Instagram in my site.
I am wondering if it is possible to overwrite the js file so as to change the word "Following" when you follow someone with just "Follow" instead. And if yes how can I do that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's on your site, then you can use Javascript (jquery would make this easier) to find the element on the page, and change the text.